# Ampliar la duración del sonido en notificaciones push android

Tags: android, push-notification, sonido

cree una aplicación en android studio la cual notifica por firebase la cual le agregue sonido por el panel hay posibilidad de alargar la duración (1 minuto) del sonido y cortar al abrir la app siendo por código como por el mismo panel ??

```
mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My Notification")
                .setContentText("NotificationMessage")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hola no te recomendaria hacer eso, ya que podrías malograr la experiencia de usuario, si este no desea que su celular suene más de lo normal. Pero, si igual quieres implementarlo puedes ponerlo como un flag de la notificacion que seria el Flag `FLAG_INSISTENT` el siguiente codigo te muestra como se implementaria.

```
Notification note = mBuilder.build();

note.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

mNotificationManager.notify(1, note);
```

Comment: Muchas gracia por tu respuesta. Entiendo lo que me aclaras que va a ser molesto para el usuario pero el cliente quiere que sea mas extenso el sonido.